# How to debug a Rails3 model that won't update or create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Help, I've broken my Rails3 user model!

I first noticed that I could not update users from the app itself.

It appears that I also can't from the rails console.

`User.save` returns `false`.

`User.create` produces a record with `id=nil`, which is not saved to the database.

I've spent two days trying to work out what the problem is. I've taken out all my CanCan and Devise validations. I've been through the code line by line. I am stumped!

Nothing in the logs is pointing me in an obvious direction.

I commented everything out of User.rb, but no joy.

I know this is a really vague question, that's almost impossible to answer from a far.

What I'm hoping is that someone can suggest logical steps for working through this and trying to figure out what's happening.

I'm still fairly new to Rails, and keen to learn how it all works.

Thanks for your ideas!

**UPDATE:**

I've been digging into this for the past week. Eventually I started a new rails app from scratch and systematically moved the old app into the new app piece by piece to try and work out where the problem lies.

I've tracked it down to my custom Devise routes.

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users,  :path_prefix => 'registration', :controllers => {:registrations => 'users/registrations'}
```

If i remove the :controllers line, then I can update the users name using the Devise user edit form.

However this is not a workable solution. The Devise edit form only provides name and email fields, but there are several other columns in my user model that the user needs access to . Hence the custom routing.

So I've tracked the issue this far, but I'm not sure where to look yet. I tried editing the registrations_controller to the default values, but no luck. (I even cut as pasted the code directly from the devise git repository).

```
def edit
  super
end

def update
  super   
end
```

So I don't think the problem is the controller.

Which leaves the form itself. The form is defined as

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put, :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
```

I can't see any issue with this. And I can't think where else to look to debug this.

To recap, the edit form displays as expected, user can edit information, click update, is redirected as expected, no errors are displayed, but the edited info is not saved. The tail shows no SQL save being called.

Very stumped, and I'd appreciate any wild ideas or suggestions!

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've eventually tracked this down to a stupid oversight on my part.

In the controller I had

```
resource.update_attributes!(params[:resource_name])
```

when what I needed was

```
resource.update_attributes!(params[resource_name])
```

An edit I must have made at some point.

A self inflicted issue that took two weeks of head scratching to resolve!

Answer (score 8):

Try this to debug in the console:

```
require 'pp'
u = User.new
u.save
pp u.errors
```

This should give you the errors that prevent the user from being saved to the DB.

Comment: @wukerplank thanks for the tip and (face plant!) if I'd remembered to restart my rails console after disabling validations, I wouldn't have had a problem there! So, as it turns out, I *can* modify users in the console, but I *can not* in the app itself. The tail logs show the updated data being posted, but no save being run. Any idea where I should look next?

Comment: @Andy Harvey To debug this issue use in your controller `@user.save!` or `@user.create!` this will raise the validation error right into your web browser.

Comment: @dombesz thanks for the suggestion. I am using .update_attributes. Will this work too? What's strange is that the only message I get is "You updated your account successfully." But the record definitely is not updated. I've posed an extract from the tail to http://pastebin.com/LUmqxbip. I feel that there should be a SQL "save" just before the |paperclip| line. But I may be wy off the mark?

Comment: @Andy Harvey Devise adds attr_accessible to your model, so only certain attributes can be updated, the rest is ignored. Try to define more attr_accessible attributes. Yes `update_attributes!` should work as well.

Comment: @dombesz thanks for your help. att_accessible are definitely defined for all variables in the POST (see the post bin link above). Should I be enabling anything else? Also will the whole update fail if one of the attributes is not accessible? Or only that attribute? One thing I notice, the HTML5 date selector is posting each 'DOB' date element as a separate attribute. How should I handle these in attr_accessible? Is :dob enough, or do I need to enable :dob(2i) etc. Thanks for helping

Comment: @Andy Harvey only the not accessible attributes are ignored, the rest should be updated. Yes, you have to enable for each :dob(2i) etc.. But in your log i don't see any sql update statements.

Comment: @dombesz thanks for the clarification. I thought there was something missing from the log! Where do I begin searching to find out why the sql update is not being called? Unless specifically defined in the controller, Rails normally handles this behind the scenes, doesn't it? Sorry for the barrage of questions, I'm feeling lost with this!

Comment: Thanks for all your great suggestions. Unfortunately  I still haven't found a solution, and this the final issue preventing launch! Updating the user is not calling a sql update, and the new parameters are not saved. Other than user.rb and user_controller.rb, where else should I be looking to debug this? Thanks